# I want my web application made on Netbeans to go online?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans, web-hosting

I have created a website which uses JSP and Servlets.
On the client side it uses javascript, jquery and AJAX(prototype methods).
The database is stored in mySQL.
I am new to website hosting, and I have no clue how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create WAR of your application. You should have domain and host account which has Servlet Container like Tomcat and just deploy your WAR file there.

Comment: I have a war file in the project folder already created.Now I need a domain and a web hosting service. Am I right? 
And could you suggest me any good Servlet Container providers?

Comment: Yes, you need a domain and hosting. http://www.mochahost.com/java.php is good one. And Tomcat would be your choice for deployment.

Comment: I dont have a server. I run tomcat through netbeans just to run it on my system. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Your question was to make your app online. So, you just get domain + hosting service which provides Tomcat. That's it.

Comment: So the hosting service that would support tomcat, are they going to charge me for the server which they are going to proved me too? 
P.S. Sorry for the stupid questions. I am new to this. I dont exactly know whether a server is provided when I purchase a web hosting service.

Comment: You probably choose shared hosting plan due to low cost around $3-$5 per month, which includes Tomcat server.

Comment: I am going with the $5.57/mo plan at mochahost.com/java.php (second one, Business Plan Private JVM). Is it alright?

Comment: Okay..Thanks :) 
Could you tell me what type of server hosting are they going to provide? shared hosting? or the virtual private server hosting?

Comment: Better ask with them. I think they provide shared hosting coz private hosting cost a lot.

Comment: Yes I talked to them. They are providing shared hosting. 
Thank you so much for helping me out. You are a lifesaver.
I didnt have anyone to guide me. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

After build the project you can get a war file in the project folder  and deploy that war file into the web-inf folder  present in host account

Comment: Could you help me with any good hosting services? Also I dont have a domain with me. I am sorry I am totally clueless about how I should proceed further.